# .net (C#) - Crear menú (switch) y validar opción antes de continuar

Tags: c#, .net, menú

Muy buenas gente, hoy necesito ayuda en validar un menú hecho con switch en visual estudio .net(c#), el cual me permita enviar un error y a la vez crear bucle si no se ingresa la opción 1 del menú, es decir:

Menú:
1. generar números al azar
2. mostrar números.
3. Salir.

si ingreso  "2" antes que la opción "1" el programa lance "error", ya que es necesario generar los números antes de mostrarlos y vuelva a mostrar el menú nuevamente hasta que se ingrese la opción 1, además me permita luego de generar los números, volver al menú a mostrarlos hasta que la opción sea "3" "salir".

De ante manos,muchas gracias, si no entienden la formulación de la pregunta,estaré atento a los comentarios.

Mi código:

```
namespace Numeritos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int menu = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
            bool validar, semaforo;
            Random valorGenerado = new Random();
            //            
            do
            {
                /* SEMAFORO ES UNA VARIABLE QUE PERMITE MANEJAR SI SE REPITE O NO EL BUCLE DEL MENU
                   ESTO PERMITE REPETIR EL PROCESO DE GENERAR LOS NUMEROS, VER LOS NUMEROS, ETC.
                   SI SEMAFORO ES FALSO EL BUCLE SE REPITE, SI ES VERDADERO EL PROGRAMA SE CIERRA.*/
                //
               semaforo = false;
               //MENU
               Console.WriteLine("Numeritos" +
          "\n 1.Generar 2 números Aleatorios." +
          "\n 2.Mostrará los números generados." +
          "\n 3.Mostrará los números que hay entre ambos empezando por el más pequeño." +
          "\n 4.Mostrar paridad." +
          "\n 5.Salir.\n");
          //
          //VALIDAR MENU
          do
          {
              do
              {
                  Console.Write("Elija Opción: ");
                  validar = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menu);
              } while (!validar);
          } while (menu < 1 || menu > 5);
          //
          //VALIDAR OPCION DE 1 A 4 SI NO, SALIR.
          if (menu != 5)
          {

               switch (menu)
               {
                   //SE GENERAN LOS NUMEROS
                   case 1:
                     num1 = valorGenerado.Next(100);
                     num2 = valorGenerado.Next(100);
                     Console.WriteLine("\n1.Se han generado sus numeros con exito.");
                     Console.ReadKey();
                     ; break;
                   case 2:
                     //MUESTRA LOS NUMEROS GENERADOS
                     Console.WriteLine("\n2.Sus numeros generados son: ");
                     Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
                     Console.WriteLine("Primer numero generado: " + num1);
                     Console.WriteLine("Segundo numero generado: " + num2);
                     semaforo = false;
                     Console.ReadKey();
                     ; break;
                   case 3:
                     //MENOR A MAYOR
                     Console.WriteLine("\n3.Menor y Mayor");
                     Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
                     //SI EL NUMERO 1 ES MAYOR AL NUMERO 2, EL 2 ES MAS PEQUEÑO 
                    if (num1 > num2)
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("El más pequeño: " + num2 +
"\nEl más grande: " + num1);
}
                         //SI EL NUMERO 2 ES MAYOR AL NUMERO 1, EL 1 ES MAS PEQUEÑO 
                    else
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("El más pequeño: " + num1);
                         Console.WriteLine("El más grande: " + num2);
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    semaforo = false;
                    ; break;
                  case 4:
                    //PARIDAD
                    Console.WriteLine("\n4.Paridad de numeros.");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
                    //SI EL RESTO (LO QUE SOBRA) DE LA DIVICIÓN DE EL NUMERO GENERADO ENTRE 2 ES 0
                    // DEVUELVE PAR, SI DEVUELVE RESTO ES IMPAR. EJ: 20 / 2 = 10 SOBRAN "0" = PAR || 20 / 3 = 6 (18) SOBRAN "2" = IMPAR.
                    if (num1 % 2 == 0)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("El numero " + num1 + " Es Par.");
                    }  
                    else
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("El numero " + num1 + " Es Impar.");
                    }
                    if (num2 % 2 == 0)
                    {
                      Console.Write("El numero " + num2 + " Es Par.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     Console.Write("El numero " + num2 + " Es Impar.");
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    semaforo = false;
                    ; break;
                }
          }

          //                 
          else
          {
              //CUANDO SE INGRESA LA OPCION 5 EL PROGRAMA DE CIERRA.
              semaforo = true;
          }
          //LIMPIAR PANTALLA CADA VEZ QUE SE REPITE EL BUCLE   
          Console.Clear();
          //                   
          //
         } while (semaforo == false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes agregar una parte del codigo que hallas intentado realizar, te recuerdo que esta pagina por asi decirlo, es el ultimo recurso al que debes acceder, ya que primero debes haber leido, investigado y tratado de realizar el codigo, si te surgio algun error y no funciono en ese momento si pasas para aca :)

te invito al [tour] por la pagina para que conozcas la manera correcta de preguntar :).

Si publicas parte de lo que has intentado te puedo ayudar

Comment: Hola amigo,gracias por la ayuda, agregue el código a la pregunta, ya investigue lo que pude y intente validar con un if, pero si valido de forma que if(menu == 1), solo me genera los números pero no puedo ingresar a la opción 2 ya que se repite el bucle luego del switch, no logro que luego de generar los números, me permita seleccionar las otras opciones...

Comment: trataste de que luego de hacer el bucle muestre el menu de nuevo?

Puedes hacer que el primer menu mostrado en la opcion 2 te diga automaticamente que no hay numeros y muestre el menu, en el caso de darle 1 y te genere los numeros, te muestre otro menu donde la opcion 2 si esta habilitada, ya te ayudo mejor que tengo la mano izquierda semi enyesada jejejeje

Comment: Mete luego del case 1; que se muestre otra vez el switch con las 5 opciones (menu principal) y en el menu principal quitas de la opcion 2 el mensaje de los numeros.

Es decir habran dos menus, el primero te mostrara las 5 opciones pero la 2da solo dira que uses la primera, y el segundo menu se mostrara unicamente al pulsar la primera y este la opcion 2 tendra los valores y el mensaje de ellos.

Otra forma seria que cuando entres a la opcion valides si num1 y num2  son mayores a cero si lo son muestra sus valores.

OJO; debes mostrar de nuevo el menu cuando hagas la seleccion de la opcion

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGO!!!, lo que hice fue tomar la idea de dividir el menú en 2 switch:

1 switch me genera los números aleatorios
2 switch me muestra todos los resultados

,entonces, al validar que num1 y num2 sea > a 0, me permite seguir el bucle sin problemas!!!, si no , me arroja error hasta que genero los números :D.

muchas gracias crack!!!, un abrazo.

Comment: jejejeje tranquilo, publica tu solucion pues aunque te dije la idea tu la resolviste. si la publicas ayudaras a otra person que pued pasar por lomismo